# Flash media server alternatives for video streaming

Tags: apache-flex, flash-media-server

I'm looking for some free media servers for live streaming of video/audio, it would be great if it has HD support; also it would be good if it would be something .net related, because I'm making the server side in asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard good things about [Red5](http://osflash.org/red5).  It's an opensource FMS alternative that supports video and audio streaming.

Comment: yep, i also started to use it, it's interesting how do ppl combine the 2 asp.net and red5, i mean the exchange of data between the swf and the asp.net

Comment: SWFs can make normal HTTP requests, and I believe there's even built-in support for webservices, so having the SWF talk to an asp.net website should be fairly trivial.  I'm not sure how you'd get the red5 server to talk to your asp.net server though (I just don't know all the capabilities of red5).